# How to set the checkbox state in local-storage after an event is fired

Tags: javascript, local-storage, game-development

I have a checkbox input that is checked by default, which toggles the visibility of an element on the page. I want users options to be saved when they refresh the page.

```
var c = document.createElement('input')
c.setAttribute("type", "checkbox")
c.checked = true

c.onclick = function(){
    if(c.checked) element.style.display = 'block'
    if(c.checked == false) element.style.display = 'none'
}

/* This code below saves the state of the checkbox,
 but never fires the event or updates the element */

c.checked = (localStorage.getItem('cchecked')== 'true');
c.onchange = function(){
    localStorage.setItem('cchecked', c.checked)
}
```

Comment: isn't that just a spello => ccchecked

Comment: nah, i just spelled it wrong when typing it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a more complete example works ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <hr id="line" />

        <script>
        var element = document.getElementById('line')
        var c = document.createElement('input')
        c.setAttribute("type", "checkbox")
        c.checked = true

        c.onclick = function(){
            if(c.checked) element.style.display = 'block'
            if(c.checked == false) element.style.display = 'none'
        }

        /* This code below saves the state of the checkbox,
         but never fires the event or updates the element */

        // c.checked = (localStorage.getItem('cchecked')== 'true');
        if (localStorage.getItem('cchecked')== 'true') {
            c.checked = true;

        }
        else if (localStorage.getItem('cchecked')== 'false') {
            c.checked = false;

        }

        c.onchange = function(){
            localStorage.setItem('cchecked', ( c.checked ? 'true' : 'false'))
        }

        if ( !c.checked) element.style.display = 'none'

        document.body.appendChild(c);
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: it's the same issue as mine, the input by default isn't set to checked

Comment: got ya - so the first checked is superfluous and the last if ( !c.checked) element.style.display = 'none' is relevant .. - glad it helped

Comment: no what i mean is , the code you sent has the same issue as mine, while both of ours saves if the box is checked or not, the default value is not checked when it should be set to checked.

Comment: that's not what your question said - and in that case your  c.checked = (localStorage.getItem('cchecked')== 'true'); is the problem see my edit

Comment: actually more like that - it's true, unless it is 'true' or 'false'

Comment: your updated code sets it by default to checked, i want the box to be set to checked by default. Once a change is made, the checkbox should remain in the state the user set it to.

Comment: I updated since that -  "it's true, unless it is 'true' or 'false'"